# Magnetic Response of Stainless Steel

Tags: magnetic-fields

Is the austenitic stainless steels, like the common 300-serie, 100% NONMAGNETIC?

Why some screws or bolts made of stainless steel, 300-serie, respond slightly to a quite strong magnetic field?

Comment: Based on the fact that you say that some bolts respond to magnetic field, I would say the answer to the first question is "no".

Comment: check this: http://www.bssa.org.uk/faq.php?id=24

Answer (score 1):

Hardly any materials are "nonmagnetic".  Most materials show some degree of attraction or reversion to a magnet.  See Permeability here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_%28electromagnetism%29

For your 300 series stainless, it appears that for common purposes at least it is considered non-magnetic  see http://www.pencomsf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/TB_MAG_SS.pdf